# Add quotes around two tuples

Tags: python, string, tuples, parentheses

I have two tuples and I would simply like to add quotes around both of them:

```
Nord = 52.2
East = 13.3
```

What I'd like to print is this statement `"52.2, 13.3"`.

However if I do print I get `'52.2', '13.3'`.

How can I get the two values in double quotes?

Comment: What do you mean? Please share your code.

Comment: What language are we talking about here?

Comment: @mszymborski = python

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  There is not so much to share. As said Nord and East are tuples. If I do `print(Nord, East)` I get `('52.5163', '13.4081')` Then I tried: `p = '"'
          print(p + Nord, East + p)` but I get `('"52.5163', '13.4081"')` What I want to have is = `"52.5163, 13.4081"` so without singular parentheses '...'

Comment: I still do not understand what the input is. See http://ideone.com/CnCPtg

Comment: Thanks a lot thats it!! In this case the input doesn't really matter!

Comment: btw, `Nord` and `East` are not `tuples` - they are `floats`

Comment: @fahrradlaus: When you have a spare minute, please consider accepting my answer that worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a simple `format()`:

```
Nord = 52.2
East = 13.3
print("\"{0}, {1}\"".format(Nord, East))
# or
print('"{0}, {1}"'.format(Nord, East))
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/CnCPtg)

Note that the `'"{0}, {1}"'` is preferred as [it is considered more *pythonic*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#string-quotes):

> In Python, single-quoted strings and double-quoted strings are the same. This PEP does not make a recommendation for this. Pick a rule and stick to it. **When a string contains single or double quote characters, however, use the other one to avoid backslashes in the string. It improves readability.**

Comment: The ugly backslashes are not needed: `'"{0}, {1}"'`

Comment: Yes, the same string. Just a little bit easier to read and that's why it is preferred by PEP8 (section String Quotes).

Comment: Ok, added a quote from PEP8.

Answer (score 1):

For any tuple `tup` (with var length) you can do this one:

```
print('"{}"'.format(', '.join(str(t) for t in tup)))
```